# JSON to GSON Modeling

Tags: android, json, gson

Given the following JSON:

```
{
"rmhc_config": {
   "show_donation": true,
   "campaignEnabled": true,
   .
   .
   .
```

I have the following class model set up

```
public class RMHCConfigModel implements Serializable{
    @SerializedName("show_donation")
    private boolean showDonation;
    @SerializedName("campaignEnabled")
    private boolean campaignEnabled;
    .
    . 
    .
```

Accessed via:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 RMHCConfigModel config = gson.fromJson(configValue.toString(), RMHCConfigModel.class);
```

I have verified configValue.toString() is returning the proper JSON in String format.

The problem is **showDonation** is being returned as **false**. I can't seem to figure out why. **campaignEnabled** is correctly returned, does this has anything to do with **showDonation** being the first element?

Thanks,
Otterman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `showDonation` to `show_Donation` in the class.

Comment: Worked thanks! Any idea why specifying @SerializedName didn't take care of it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that it would work if you used a `JSONObject` instead of `Gson`. Right now, it seems like `showDonation` is getting the default java value for boolean, which is false.

Answer (score 0):

Your java structure isn't correct.

It should be like this :

```
public class GlobalConfig {

    @SerializedName("rmhc_config")
    private RMHCConfigModel rmhc;

    public static GlobalConfig fromJson(String json) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, GlobalConfig.class);
    }

    public String toJson() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }

}

public class RMHCConfigModel {

    @SerializedName("show_donation")
    private boolean showDonation;

    @SerializedName("campaignEnabled")
    private boolean campaignEnabled;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your java structure or your annotations are not right, or your JSON contains an unnecessary sub-object.

Try the following. It will work without changing the structure of your model  The campaignEnabled and showDonation attributes of the resultant config object will be true:

```
     String configValue = "{\"show_donation\": true,\"campaignEnabled\": true}";
     RMHCConfigModel config = new Gson().fromJson(configValue.toString(), RMHCConfigModel.class);
```